# pivot python dataframe rows to columns

Tags: python

I have a python dataframe like this

```
       date      col1       col2    val
0   2019-01-01    A         hello   12
1   2019-01-01    A           hi    10
2   2019-01-02    B         hello   5
3   2019-01-02    B           hi    6
```

I want to convert it to

```
       date      col1       hello  hi
0   2019-01-01    A           12    10
1   2019-01-02    B            5    6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use pandas `pivot_table()` method. You can read more about it [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html).

The `values` belong to the `val` column, the indexes which we will retain are the `date` and `col1`, and we would like to "create" columns out of the `col2` col.

```py
df = pd.pivot_table(df, values='val', index=['date', 'col1'],columns=['col2'], aggfunc=np.sum, fill_value=0)
```

Note that might some values be `NaN`, the above function will automatically set them to `0`, as per the `fill_value` parameter.

**Input:**

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a = ['2019-01-01', 'A', 'hello', 12]
b = ['2019-01-01', 'A', 'hi', 10]
c = ['2019-01-02', 'B', 'hello', 5]
d = ['2019-01-02', 'B', 'hi', 6]
df = pd.DataFrame([a, b, c, d], columns=['date', 'col1', 'col2', 'val'])

df = pd.pivot_table(df, values='val', index=['date', 'col1'],columns=['col2'], aggfunc=np.sum, fill_value=0)

print(df)
```

**Output:**

```py
col2             hello  hi
date       col1           
2019-01-01 A        12  10
2019-01-02 B         5   6
```